# Uniqueness of the solution of a nonlinear PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Given the nonlinear PDE
$$
    \partial^2\phi+\phi^3=0
$$
I consider the characteristics $\xi=\kappa\cdot x$. Then I look for a solution in the form
$$
    \phi(x)=a\cdot\chi(\xi).
$$
Then, provided $\kappa^2=\frac{a}{2}$, I get the ODE defining of the Jacobi ${\rm sn}$ function and the final solution takes the form
$$
   \phi(x)=a\cdot{\rm sn}(\xi+b,-1).
$$
This solution has two arbitrary integration constants $a$ and $b$ that yield a family of solutions of the PDE we started from.

My question is this: Could I claim this set of solutions to be unique in some sense? Otherwise, under what conditions this claim could be supported? It is generally known that such a nonlinear equation could provide rich families of solutions so, this question appears to me not that easy to address.

Comment: With the necessary pinch of salt, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28y%27%27%28x%29+%2B+y%28x%29^3+%3D+0%2C+x%29) seems to corroborate your statement.

Comment: Why did you put this on hold? What is wrong with this formulation of the question? Please, check these papers http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1955 http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.2351 http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6530 http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4053 Why should not this question fit your criteria for research level?

Comment: The question I tried to ask is how general are these solutions. Please, could you suggest a better rewording?